# How to find the following Friday after a pay period ends

Tags: excel, weekday

My company pays every Friday on the sales from the previous week. Our work period goes from Sunday to Saturday, and we get paid every following Friday for any work done in that pay period.

I have the dates of my sales in column J, and I want the corresponding payday to appear in column M. So if J1 had 1/14/17, M1 would return 1/20/17. The formula I found is:

```
=J1+7-WEEKDAY(J1+1)+7.
```

This works almost perfectly except that any sales made on a Saturday don't get paid out for 13 days, and they should get paid out in 6 days.  So how do I change this to get what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element that snaps a particular day to a particular week is the `weekday()` function.  So you need to adjust the input to weekday function by one day and then compensate by adding one less day at the end.

So you need:

```
=J1-WEEKDAY(J1)+13
```

Instead of:

```
 =J1-WEEKDAY(J1+1)+14
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thanks so much for your help on that!